# How to validate xml using python without third-party libs?

Tags: python

I have some xml pieces like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE mensaje SYSTEM "record.dtd">
<record>
    <player_birthday>1979-09-23</player_birthday>
    <player_name>Orene Ai'i</player_name>
    <player_team>Blues</player_team>
    <player_id>453</player_id>
    <player_height>170</player_height>
    <player_position>F&W</player_position>   <---- a '&' here.
    <player_weight>75</player_weight>
</record>
```

Is there any way to validate whether the xml pieces is well-formatted? 
Is there any way to validate the xml against a DTD or XML Scheme?

For various reasons **I can't use any third-party packages.**

e.g. the xml above is not conrrect since it has a '&' in it. Note that the DOCTYPE definition sentence refer to a DTD.

Comment: I consider it risky, to violate XML on token level (level-0) and hope to find a tool, which checks for level-1 compliance. The probability to find one is not higher in first-party tools. If I count correctly in the backtrace, the answer of jsbueno fails due to that. Why is replacing by "&amp;" not an option?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just try to parse it with ElementTree (xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring)  - it will raise an error if the XML is not well formed.

```
>>> a = """<record>
...     <player_birthday>1979-09-23</player_birthday>
...     <player_name>Orene Ai'i</player_name>
...     <player_team>Blues</player_team>
...     <player_id>453</player_id>
...     <player_height>170</player_height>
...     <player_position>F&W</player_position>   <---- a '&' here.
...     <player_weight>75</player_weight>
... </record>"""
>>> 
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> x = ET.fromstring(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1282, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1624, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1488, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 7, column 24
```

Comment: How to avoid warning `FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
  if ElementTree.fromstring(output_payload):` ?

Comment: This is due to nature of `xml.etree` that makes testing `Element` objects for truthiness dependent on what's inside them (so elements that have no subelements will evaluate to `False`). That's why they write that a specific test for truthiness is needed (`if elem is not None` and not `if elem`). They decided to change this behavior. You can suppress warnings using: `with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:` and then `with contextlib.redirect_stderr(devnull): `.

Answer (score 9):

You can use python's `xml.dom.minidom` XML parser (which is in the standard library, but isn't as powerful as alternatives such as `lxml`).

Just do:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
xml.dom.minidom.parseString('<My><XML><String/><XML/><My/>')
```

You will get a `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError` if the XML is invalid.

Comment: Minidom is no longer the prefered way of parsing MXL in standard Python  (although it won't matter in this specific case, unless performance matters)

Comment: You may want to correct the XML spelling; by the way: what is the preferred way now?

Comment: @guidot jsbueno suggested the use of `ElementTree` in his own answer which is actually more powerful than `minidom` and should indeed be used! If you have access to non-standard libraries, `lxml` probably is the best out there!