# Python XML SAX to check XML well-formedness

Tags: python, xml, sax

How can I check solely the well-formedness of an XML file, skipping any DTD checks? Currently I am using the following code from the XML SAX parser:

```
 from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
 from xml.sax import make_parser
 import glob
 import os, os.path, sys
 import pdb
 import fileinput

 path = os.getcwd()

 for filenames in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
     try:
         parser = make_parser()
         parser.setContentHandler(ContentHandler())
         parser.parse(filenames)
         print ("%s is well-formed" % filenames)
     except Exception, e:
         print ("%s is NOT well-formed! %s" % (filenames, e))
```

This works great for XML files without a DTD declaration. However, when the XML does have a DTD declaration, it is declared NOT well-formed. I would like to solely check the well-formedness of the files and disregard this declaration.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52256-check-xml-well-formedness/

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742538/how-to-validate-xml-using-python-without-third-party-libs